# Connect to a network but no internet, not even the default gateway

Tags: connection, internet

I have a Raspberry Pi 4. I can establish a connection fine (wireless or cable), but packets are not getting out.
I can't even ping the default route...
Please see attached image. Sorry, typing this on my phone.

I tried: my android access point; my actual home router using WiFi. My home router using an ethernet cable. In ALL cases I get the same result

The Pi can't even reach hosts in the local network. When one of those hosts tried to ping, I see a "packet filtered" message for each ping.

What on earth could this be?

[image: not even pinging...]

Comment: What OS? How did you configure networking?